# rails 4 how to pass object_id in form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I have a Announcement that 'has_many' Comments and Comment 'belongs_to' Announcement relation. 
On my root I am displaying announcements by each loop and I try to make a comment form_for under every news.

My root_path action:

```
  def home
    @announcements = Announcement.page(params[:page]).order('id DESC')
  end
```

And here is my announcement loop:

```
<% @announcements.each do |announcement| %>
           .
           .
           .
        <div class="create_comment form-inline">
                <%= form_for(announcement.comments.build) do |form| %>
                            <%= form.label :author, "Autor:" %>
                            <%= form.text_field :author, class: "form_control" %>

                            <%= form.label :content, "Treść:" %>
                            <%= form.text_field :content, class: "form_control" %>

                            <%= form.submit "Dodaj!", class: "btn btn-primary", url: comments_path %>

                <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my comment create action:

```
  def create
      @announcement = Announcement.find(params[:comment_id])
    @comment = @announcement.comments.new(comments_params)
    if @comment.save
        flash[:success] = "Komentarz dodano"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end   
private

def comments_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:author,:content)
    end
```

But I get an error: Couldn't find Announcement without an ID

I know I could use a hidden_field and pass it to the comments_params, but this is not secure solution.

I just started my Rails adventure so If anybody knows where is my error, please try to make full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok with help from @notulysses I made it to the solution.

Chenges to be needed to make:

First in routes.rb: comments needed to be nested in announcement, to be join proper.

```
  resources :announcements, only: [:new,:create,:update,:edit,:destroy,:show] do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
```

Second in comments_controller Announcement should be find by announcement_params:

```
@announcement = Announcement.find(params[:announcement_id])
```

And by third (and this is my part :) ), I needed to proper set the form_for attributes.

```
form_for(announcement.comments.create, url: announcement_comments_path(announcement.id) )
```

It needed url: param since root was in different controller then comments.

Yupi !!!!